# php preg_replace returns 0 value when using underscore character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

My question is, why does the position of the '_' (underscore) character cause this problem?

I have inherited a script that is using php's preg_replace in a function.  The regex used is returning a 0 on any number it is used on.

```
function foo($number){ 
  $number = preg_replace('/[a-z$,-_]/i','',$number);
  // more code...
}
```

I did a bunch of debugging and found the problem was with the preg_replace().  A co-worker mentioned that the order of the characters in the regex maybe causing the bug.  So, I played with this and found it to be true.  The position of the '_' (underscore) character is the sinister culprit.  I changed this to:

```
'/[a-z$_,-]/i'
```

... and everything works fine.

So, the question, again, is why does the position of the '_' (underscore) character cause this problem?  I've Googled on this but have not found it and I thought the minds in this forum may have the answer.

Thanks for any enlightenment!
-jc

Comment: I suspect it's more the position of the `-` (hyphen) character than the underscore.

Comment: @Deadooshka trifle overzealous but yeah, that would work - you only really need to escape the hyphen in this example `'/[a-z$,\-_]/i'` since the regexp itself is in single-quotes no interpolation will occur.

Comment: [`so it is always safe to precede a non-alphanumeric with "\" to specify that it stands for itself.`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters need to be escaped like this

```
[a-z,\-_]
```

Comment: however, underscore is not one of those characters, the hyphen within the square brackets on the other hand...

Comment: escaping the hyphen does the trick.  I tested this in my script.  Both answers were spot on.

Comment: Escaping the hyphen will be more intuitive to a future coder who may inherit this script.  I've commented both solutions but who knows if the comment will remain.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

It's the position of the hyphen, not the underscore. With `[a-z$,-_]`, you're inadvertently creating a character range from `,` to `_`. Put the hyphen on the end or escape it.

Comma `,` is ASCII 0x2C, underscore `_` is 0x5F, and digits fall between those (0x30 to 0x39).
(ref: [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense and I'm kicking myself for not seeing that in the reading I've done on ranges in regexs.  I should have realized that even if the text wasn't explicit.  Cheers!